# Why does direct binding of an `our &foo` not work, but indirecting via a dynamic lookup does?

Tags: module, raku, subroutine, rakudo

Why is there a difference between r1 and r2 when called outside of module TEST?

```
module TEST {
    our &r1 := OUR::{'&r1'} := sub {
        say 'routine 1'
    }

    r1();            # routine 1

    our &r2 := sub {
        say 'routine 2'
    }

    r2();            # routine 2
}

import TEST;

say TEST::.keys;     # (&r1 &r2)

TEST::r1();          # routine 1
TEST::r2();          # Cannot invoke this object (REPR: Uninstantiable; Callable) ...
```

There is an error when trying to run subroutine r2 outside of module TEST where it was defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** Binding to an `our` is pointless. Binding to an `OUR::<&foo>` is effective. I like naming things... It seems you've invented a technique which I hereby dub "@jakar's double bind `our`".

## Why the direct binding only works inside the module

In a comment on his answer to [an earlier SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52873708/is-export-and-binding-in-perl-6) jnthn concludes that we could perhaps have an error message, or perhaps a warning, to the effect that:

> binding to an `our` variable is pointless use of `our`.

(What he means is that the binding only works inside the module, not outside, as you have discovered.)

There's an old and still open issue [Binding a variable at BEGIN time doesn't stick around for runtime](https://github.com/Raku/old-issue-tracker/issues/3676) that discusses the general problem in depth.

## Why the dynamic lookup works outside the module

From [Symbols that start with core namespaces always get exported](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1458), jnthn notes that:

> stashes are always open to poke symbols in to.

So, ignoring use of symbols *inside* your module, your code is doing this:

```
module TEST {
    OUR::{'&r1'} := sub { say 'routine 1' }
    our &r2;
}

import TEST;

TEST::r1();          # routine 1
TEST::r2();          # Cannot invoke this object (REPR: Uninstantiable; Callable) ...
```

## @jakar's double bind `our`

If one wants to be able to declare a symbol and use it both inside and outside the module *and insists on using binding* then your trick of declaring it with a double bind may be the best technique available:

```
    our &r1 := OUR::{'&r1'} := sub { ... }
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ works *outside* module
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ works *inside* module
```

Some things I'm curious about:

- Have you been able to *confirm* any significant *specific* and *practical* advantage(s) that can be accrued from binding instead of assigning an `our`?
- Do folk want to get around the "binding to an `our` variable is pointless" issue? If so, would they be happy to use @jakar's double bind `our`?
- Does your technique apply to all sigils? (I would expect so but will leave it to you to explore such aspects. :))